# Django array value in a form

Tags: python, django, forms

I have the ability submit tags in a form. When the form is submitted, I see:

`tags=['3','4','5']`

The tag values are ID's for what the user has chosen. I am able to get the values from the `request.POST` object and everything is fine. Problem is that the user has to select ATLEAST one tag. And I want to do the validation in a Django form, but I'm not sure what kind of form field value to supply in the django form? Normally I use `CharField`, `DateField`, etc. But what exists to get the array value? And then I can supply a `clean` function for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `django.forms.MultipleChoiceField()`.
See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield

```
known_tags = (
    (1, 'Choice 1'), (2, 'Choice 2'), (3, 'Choice 3'),
    (4, 'Choice 4'), (5, 'Choice 5'))

class MyForm(django.forms.Form):
    tags = django.forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=known_tags, required=True)
```

**EDIT 1:**

If what you want to do is to turn a text field into an array...

```
class MyForm(django.forms.Form):
    tags = django.forms.CharField(required=True)

    def clean_tags(self):
        """Split the tags string on whitespace and return a list"""
        return self.cleaned_data['tags'].strip().split()
```

Comment: No, this would not work. I do not have a set of "Known tags". I have a table in the database, so the tags could be anything on that table.

Comment: The choices tuple is just an example. You can pull the data from your db and build the list. Or, are you saying you allow users to enter text (rather than select from a list)?

Comment: Yeah, users are able to enter text... Because these values are from tags.

Comment: Sorry @kalvish, I don't know what you mean. An example would help

Comment: Found a solution to my problem... http://slacy.com/blog/2012/04/array-valued-form-fields-in-django/