# How Can I Create Array Form Input in Django

Tags: django, forms

I have the following form input in my template that displays questions from the database.

```
<input type="text" name="qus[{{ question.id }}]" id="qus" value="{{ question.quest }}" />
```

I created my Django form with:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
      qus = SimpleArrayField(forms.CharField(max_length = 50))
```

Each time I submit the form, it does'nt work. It seems the form is not valid

```
 MyQuestionForm = QuestionForm(request.POST)
 if request.method == "POST" and MyQuestionForm.is_valid():
```

How can I create the form properly and loop through request.POST['qus'] to retrieve all the values when I submit the form? Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django array value in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705621/django-array-value-in-a-form)

Comment: Thanks Shayan, but I don't think this help. This is the html array input field:    <input type="text" name="qus[{{ question.id }}]" id="qus" value="{{ question.quest }}" />   which means it will have array variable such as qus[1], qus[2], qus[3] etc. How do I retrieve the values in the array in Django?

Comment: Well it depends on your queryset and this is not the exact answer but can give some hints.

Comment: Thank you. I rename the input field to qus[] instead of the passing value to is as in qus[{{ question.id }}]. I got it working with qus[].